# Python Gtk3: NoteBook Resizing width

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

Working with Python & Gtk3, I'm using a `Gtk.Box` or `GtkBox` for my main container.
Here's my code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk,Gdk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Simple Notebook Example")
        self.set_border_width(3)
        self.set_default_size(1200, 648)

        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=1)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.notebook1 = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.box.pack_start(self.notebook1, True, True, 0)

        self.notebook2 = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.box.pack_end(self.notebook2, True, True, 0)
##################################################################################################
        self.page1 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page1.set_border_width(10)
        self.notebook1.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label('Tab Pane 1 panel 1'))
###################################################################################################
        self.page1 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page1.set_border_width(10)

        self.notebook2.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label('Tab Pane 1 panel 2'))

        self.page2 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page2.set_border_width(10)
        self.notebook2.append_page(self.page2, Gtk.Label('Tab Pane 2 panel 2'))

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Here's the the output :

[image: Result (window)]

So how could I resize from notebook1 and add that size to notebook2 without losing space in the window?

Comment: I edited your post and my edit will be reviewed. Please don't use tags that don't relate, such as `pygobject` and `gtk2`. Also, I realize that English is probably not your first language, but your question is very unclear. I might answer it except that I don't understand it. I'm just wondering as well why you are initializing and setting the border width of `page1` twice, and what the hashtags surrounding the one piece of code are for??

Comment: @oldtechaa `pygtk` is the tag that does not relate; this is using `pygobject`, not `pygtk` (which only supports GTK+ 2).

Comment: @أحمد بوعبيد I'm afraid I do not understand the question. Can you make an edited screenshot that shows what you want to do?

Comment: OK, thanks. I don't use Python, so I thought `pygtk` was the binding for all versions.